# SQL How to compute a specific value for each tuple in a relation?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me elaborate here.

**EDIT**:

Let's say I have a relation that is `r(person_name, age);`

This is what I want to calculate: For each person in the relation, I want to calculate the **number** of other people who have the same age as that person.

I want to basically inner join on the `age` attribute and I will get all the `person_name` tuples with the same age attribute. Then I need to count the number of rows in that result tuple. That gives me the number of people who have the same age as the person whom I calculated this query on. **I know how to do all this**.

What I don't know is how to do it **FOR EVERY PERSON** in the table.

My end table should look something like this:

```
person_name | num_of_people_with_same_age
------------------------------------------
      A     | 3
      B     | 2
      C     | 0
            |
```

This is equivalent to a double for-loop in regular programming languages. I just don't know how to think of it in SQL terms.

Comment: show some sample data in the table(s) and the expected output.

Comment: SQL deals with tables. What is your schema?

Comment: Please provide an some DDL and DML statements for your sample data and an example of your expected output for that data.

Comment: Pls check edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE r ( Person_name, Age ) AS
SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Person_Name,
       COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY Age ) AS num_people_with_same_age
FROM   r;
```

**Output**:

```
PERSON_NAME NUM_PEOPLE_WITH_SAME_AGE
----------- ------------------------
E                                  2 
C                                  2 
B                                  1 
A                                  3 
D                                  3 
F                                  3 
G                                  1
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand now